# Python regex to capture text between two matches?

Tags: python, regex

I would like to use a regular expression that matches any text between two strings:

```
DATE POSTED: MAY 30, 2018, some text here, Garcia Answer 1: more text, DATE POSTED: MARCH 8, 2017, some text here, Smith Answer 2: more text, DATE POSTED: JUNE 17, 2018, some text here, Jones Answer 1: more text...
```

In this example, I would like to search for the `DATE POSTED: [*date*],`  and  `, [*Name*] Answer [*number*]:` and grab everything in between.

In other words, I'd like to find all `some text here`

I'm using Python 3x.

Comment: Does [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/1) help?

Comment: Since, you're a new contributor; so there might be a chance that you might not have read the documentation of how to accept an answer. If any answer helps, please consider accepting it by checking the tick mark below it. It is helpful both for the answerer as well as the community since the future readers get benefited from the posts. Although; it is not any hurry to accept an answer. Take your time to find the best answer suited to you but be sure to accept it after finding the answer that best suits you. For better insights please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Please acknowledge whether you need something else from the answers?

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re 

t = "DATE POSTED: MAY 30, 2018, some text here, Garcia Answer 1: more text, DATE POSTED: MARCH 8, 2017, some text here, Smith Answer 2: more text, DATE POSTED: JUNE 17, 2018, some text here, Jones Answer 1: more text..."


out = re.split("Answer [0-9]{1}",t)

out = [",".join(x.split(",")[0:-1]) for x in out]

out = [re.split("[0-9]{4},",x) for x in out]

out = [x[-1] for x in out]

print(out)
```

will print everything out as a list

Comment: Thanks for the response. The examples I posted earlier are actually part of the same string (see edit)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import re
s = "DATE POSTED: MAY 17, 2018, some text here, Garcia Answer 1: more text"
print(re.findall(r'(?<=DATE POSTED: MAY 17, 2018, )(.*)(?=, Garcia Answer 1)',s))
```

Output:

```
['some text here']
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. But your solution only works for 1 very specific example. Is there a way to extract all the "some text here"?

Answer (score 0):

You may try:

```
DATE POSTED: .*?, \d{4}, (.*?),
```

**Explanation of the above regex:**

> **`DATE POSTED: .*?,`** - Matches `DATE POSTED:`  literally along with everything after it before the first `,`. That is the reason I used lazy matching i.e. `.*?`.
>
> **`\d{4},`** - Matches the year part i.e. `\d{4}` represents 4 year digits before a `,`.
>
> **`(.*?),`** - Represents a capturing group matching everything after it **lazily** before  the first `,` character.

You can find the demo of the above regex in [**here.**](https://regex101.com/r/vjNu4U/7)

[image: Pictorial Representation]

**Implementation in python:**

```
import re

regex = r"DATE POSTED: .*?, \d{4}, (.*?),"

test_str = "DATE POSTED: MAY 30, 2018, some text here1, Garcia Answer 1: more text, DATE POSTED: MARCH 8, 2017, some text here2, Smith Answer 2: more text, DATE POSTED: JUNE 17, 2018, some text here3, Jones Answer 1: more text..."

matches = re.findall(regex, test_str)
print(matches)
# For making a difference between strings I used "some text here1, 2 and 3".
# output: matches = ['some text here1', 'some text here2', 'some text here3']
```

You can find the sample run of the above implementation in [**here.**](https://onlinegdb.com/H1DO6YrpI)